# Why is this Express middleware not being called with arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am working on a middleware that needs `bodyParser` to run, but I don't want to make the app bring that in as a dependency. Instead, I want to make a package that requires that and exports a middleware like this:

```
//routes.js
app.use('/', middlewareWrapper(thing));

//middlware.js
export function middlewareWrapper(thing) {
    return function addBody(req, res, next) {
        function othermiddleware(_req, _res) {
            // do something with thing and _req
            return next();
        }
        return bodyParser.json()(req, res, othermiddleware);
    };
}
```

This looks like it would work, and the `othermiddleware` is called, but with no arguments.

I found another answer that addresses this in basically the same way (it's old, but JS still works the same way): https://stackoverflow.com/a/17997640/444871

Why is the `othermiddleware` being called with no args?

Comment: I believe the middleware returned by `bodyParser.json()` simply call `next()` like this (i.e. with no argument). Here you are passing `othermiddleware` as `next` to the middleware returned by `bodyParser.json()`. So it does not contain any argument.

Comment: You are exactly right. My coworker pointed this out, too. If you make this the answer I will accept it.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the middleware returned by `bodyParser.json()` simply call `next()` like this (i.e. with no argument). Here you are passing `othermiddleware` as next to the middleware returned by `bodyParser.json()`. Therefore it does not contain any argument.

Also the bodyParser does not change the original reference of `req/res` object. So the main `req/res` object still refer to the same object. So you dont need arguments to be passed. You can simply use the same `req/res` object in your `othermiddleware` function too.

```
return function addBody(req, res, next) {
        function othermiddleware() {
            // You should be able to use req and res modified by bodyParser.
            // You dont need arguments to be passed.
            return next();
        }
        return bodyParser.json()(req, res, othermiddleware);
    };
```

Comment: IIRC bodyparser adds a body object to the req object.

Comment: @DLowther It adds a `body` property to `req` object. It does not change the reference of `req` object. Thats what i have written.

Answer (score 1):

Cause you do

```
next();
```

without passing parameters. Usually express does sth like that:

```
bodyParser.json()(
  req,
  res,
  () => {
    othermiddleware(req,res,next);
  }
);
```

Or you use some bind magic:

```
bodyParser.json()(req, res, othermiddleware.bind(this,req,res,next));
```